# Why does it not evaluate even powers of -1 to 1?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I cannot understand why

```
Assuming[n\[Element]Integers,(-1)^(2n)]
```

is not evaluated to 1, instead I obtain

```
(-1)^(2n)
```

What do I have to do to obtain "1" here?

Comment: Try `Assuming[n \[Element] Integers, Simplify[(-1)^(2 n)]]`  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJoRY.png)

Comment: This works, but it does not work here: V[k_,l_]:=Assuming[k\[Element]Integers && l\[Element]Integers, Simplify[(2 Integrate[(1/Pi) (-q) DiracDelta[x-Pi]Cos[k x] Cos[l x],{x,0,Pi}])]/.{HeavisideTheta[0]->1}]  for V[2n,2m].

Comment: `Refine[(-1)^(2n),n\[Element]Integers]`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
V[k_,l_]:=Assuming[k[Element]Integers && l[Element]Integers, Simplify[(2 Integrate[(1/Pi) (-q) DiracDelta[x-Pi]Cos[k x] Cos[l x],{x,0,Pi}])]/.{HeavisideTheta[0]->1}] 
V[2n,2m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can do the following. Add `2*k` and `2*L` inside the definition, now it knows it is even

```
V[k_, L_] := Assuming[Element[k, Integers] && Element[L, Integers], 
   Simplify[(2 Integrate[(1/Pi) (-q) DiracDelta[x - Pi] Cos[2*k x] Cos[2*L x], {x, 0, Pi}])] /. {HeavisideTheta[0] -> 1}];
V[n, m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Because in your version, it does not know the input is even integer. You just told it is integer.

Comment: I understand, but how can I define it without breaking the definition of V and such that it automatically detects if the exponential of -1 is an even integer during the evaluation?

Comment: @RaphaelJ.F.Berger although I did not verify you could maybe do as shown here then use a substitution rule `/. {k->k/2,L->L/2}` at the end of the definition.